# How to trace IIS worker process requests

Tags: iis, request, monitoring

I need to be able to monitor requests from IIS w3wp processes.

How can I see IIS worker process Requests?

Comment: If your question reads like a shopping question, lots of people will just vote to close based upon that.  Try to avoid key phrases such as "looking for a tool".  Instead just clearly define what you need to accomplish.  Even if you don't explicitly use the word `tool` answers are still likely to suggest one if it seems like the best solution to the requirement.

Comment: Also, I've edited your post so that it doesn't seem like a shopping question.  You might want to look it over, and make sure that I didn't cause any of your requirement to be lost

Comment: Thanks Sam, I like the way you edit my question, it gets better.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

To trace all requests currently executing in IIS worker processes

- Open a command window and type `logman startsession name–p "IIS:
  Request Monitor" -ets` and press <kbd>ENTER</kbd>.
- Event Tracing for Windows prints to the screen details about the
  trace session you just started, including the name of the session,
  the file name where the trace data will be collected (session
  name.etl by default), and whether or not the command was successful
- Allow the trace session to run until you have reproduced the problem
  or until your sites have processed enough requests to produce a
  manageable data set
- From the command prompt, type `logman stopsession name-ets` and press
  <kbd>ENTER</kbd>.

Answer (score 3):

I'm not as experienced on Windows vs Linux so Ravindra's answer seems interesting (is this just scheduling a particular event viewer style session or actually logging out deeper?).

As you particularly ask about 'IIS worker process Requests' you have two options.

**GUI**

Open inetmgr, go to the root server level, go to Worker Processes and double-click the worker process of your choice. A new screen will load and you will see anything that worker is currently processing.

**Command-line**

Rather than just give you a single command to copy and paste this article is a great starter - http://www.iis.net/learn/get-started/getting-started-with-iis/getting-started-with-appcmdexe

The particular command you want is under the section 'INSPECTING CURRENTLY EXECUTING REQUESTS'